# Cocos2d: Slowly reveal a sprite( think WoW spell cooldown )

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, glsl

I'm wanting to create a WoW cooldown effect where a player does some action and is not able to do the action again until the sprite is fully shown again. I have a grayed out version of the same sprite and am wanting to slowly reveal the sprite until it is fully available again. So, there will be a slow blend vertically of the gray and colored sprite.

Is there a way to do this with built in functionality with Cocos2d and CCSprite?

I'm using v2 of Cocos2d so I could write a shader which I think would be pretty easy, but before I went this route I wanted to see if there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look to the CCProgressTimer class. If I understand right, it will make what you want

Comment: interesting, now make a CCMenuItemWithProgressTimer and i'm in business. Thanks Morion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CCFadeIn to animate the colored sprite over the grayed sprite :

```
[coloredSprite runAction:[CCFadeIn actionWithDuration:1.0f];
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. I went with CCProgressTimer.